# When using the child_process.spawn() method with {stdio: 'inherit'}, is it possible for the parent receive output from the child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, child-process

I've tried reading subprocess.stdout but node docs clearly state "If the child was spawned with stdio[1] set to anything other than 'pipe', then this will be null." which isn't what I want because I need to inherit.

Also tried using process.send() in my child process, but that didn't work either.

Here's my code btw:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('node index.js', {
    shell: process.env.ComSpec, 
    stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> `"inherit"`: Pass through the corresponding stdio stream to/from the parent process.

So does manually piping the streams to the parent’s, too.

```
stdio: ["inherit", "pipe", "pipe"]
```

```
import Process from "node:process";

executable_process.stdout.pipe(Process.stdout);
executable_process.stdout.on("data", chunk => …);
executable_process.stderr.pipe(Process.stderr);
executable_process.stderr.on("data", chunk => …);
```

Forward the stream data to the parent’s streams and while doing that, peek into the data with the `"data"` event listener.

Note that the `"data"` event listener will not be triggered if you give it the `"inherit"` option; you need to *manually* set the piping destination with the `"pipe"` option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
{ 
...
stdio: ["pipe", "inherit", "inherit"] 
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio

Comment: I guess this is not what the author is asking. Here you are piping the _input_ of the child process, which gives you an ability to send data _to_ the child process. While the author is asking how to receive data _from_ the child process.

Comment: Im not "pipe"ing, Im "inherit"ing stdout

Answer (score -6):

Yes you can, the answer can be found on the Node.js document [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process).

If you are running this on Windows, [read this section](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows), you will want to make sure the child process runs within a terminal (cmd.exe on Windows).

You should be able to use:

```
const child = spawn('node index.js', ['/c', 'my.bat']);
```

OR

```
exec('node index.js', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Basically calling "**spawn(...)**" will return a ChildProcess, which is an **EvenEmitter**. It has two output streams, "**stderr**", "**stdout**", which you will listen for "data" events on.

- You read the error output from the spawned(child) process on the "**stderr**" stream.
- You read normal output from the spawned(child) process on the "**stdout**" stream.

How to listen for normal output and error:

```
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
```

To know when the child process has existed, listen for the "**close**" event

```
child.on('close', (code) => {
  // Perform cleanup.
});
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry no one ever explained the down votes.  Basically, when the stdio "inherit" option is given, the `child.stdout.on` streams are silent.  We're looking for a workaround to allow the stdout to be sent to the terminal, with all syntax highlighting and such, while also being able to access the stream from the app.